# Is there a pandas way to automatically have nice names for columns to use in legends or similar graph items?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any pandas way to "link" a dataframe column name with a nice description for that name?

See the following snippet where I have a dataframe with two column: the weight in kg and the height in meter of ten people.

When I create the dataframe I use this syntax

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]})
```

but I would like to "attach" in the creation of the dataframe a `beautiful description for column name a` and `$\b_0$ some latex for column name b` so that all the graph items that automatically use that names appears nice to the user (legend, tick labels, axis labels and so on).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sz = 10
bmi = np.random.normal(25,0.1,sz)
h = np.random.normal(70*2.54/100,4*2.54/100,sz)
w = bmi*h**2
df = pd.DataFrame({'height_m':h,'weight_kg':w})
ax1 = df.plot.scatter(x='height_m',y='weight_kg')
plt.savefig('raw.png')
ax2 = df.plot.scatter(x='height_m',y='weight_kg')
ax2.set_xlabel('$h_0$, Altezza/m')
ax2.set_ylabel('$p_0$, Peso/kg')
plt.savefig('publishable.png')
plt.show()
```

This is the raw picture straight from pandas:

[image: raw picture straight from pandas]

This is the picture I would like to get... but without modifying by myself the plot adding `set_xlabel` and `set_ylabel` and so on...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can name your `DataFrame` correctly from the beginning and plot the dataframe accessing `df.columns`:

```
sz = 10
bmi = np.random.normal(25,0.1,sz)
h = np.random.normal(70*2.54/100,4*2.54/100,sz)
w = bmi*h**2
df = pd.DataFrame({'$h_0$, Altezza/m':h,'$p_0$, Peso/kg':w})
df.plot.scatter(x=df.columns[0], y=df.columns[1])
plt.savefig('publishable.png')

plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

Plus, if you are using `Jupyter Notebook / Jupyter Lab`, it will convert the LaTeX correctly:
[image: dataframe]